# Remove inequality signs in Powerline

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-powerline

I installed Powerline for vim and am using an unpatched font, so it is showing [Inequality signs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXwMc.png). Is there a way to remove them?
Using a patched font doesn't change a thing, powerline still have the same look.

Comment: Which do you use? [Vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) or [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline)?

Comment: I have the same issue with both plugins, the screenshot is from vim-powerline, but I don't mind at all switching to vim-airline. :)

Comment: use patched font and change font of your terminal emulator to that font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the dividers you can put this in your `_vimrc`

```
let g:Powerline_dividers_override = ['', '', '', '']
```

Then you will probably need to run `:PowerlineClearCache` and restart Vim.

Here it is in [help](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/blob/develop/doc/Powerline.txt#L202).